# Share Calendars by Default in Exchange 2007 on SBS 2008

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

We've recently set up a new domain at work using SBS 2K8 as the DC. SBS includes Exchange server.

We're able to share calendars by explicitly granting permissions to users/groups but at present we're unable to configure exchange so that when new users are added, they can automatically see all other calendars. In turn, all existing users should be able to see the new user's calendar.

As I'm a complete novice when it comes to managing exchange, I'd appreciate it if someone could point me at some good resources.

Googling "exchange auto share calendar" and similar shows results related to syncing exchange with Google, blackberries, etc...

Presumably there's a more accurate term to search for but again, I don't know it.

Many thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure Outlook is not in Cache mode so the auto replication of exchange to AD or the opposite should be instantly done.

Can you check that feature?

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear - If I manually grant "Reviewer" permissions on a calendar, it works - What I want to do is automatically make all users reviewers of all calendars as soon as they are added to the system (and for existing users to be able to review the new users' calendar).

Comment: Sorry, my bad!

Maybe you will find what you are looking for in this ServerFault thread: http://serverfault.com/questions/198/how-might-i-grant-access-to-everyones-calendar-in-exchange-2007

Comment: That would've been far more sensible - Until now, I've only used StackOverflow

Thanks :)

Comment: As the chinese people: Thank you, come again!!! haha